# How to pull data from mysql server into android device?

Tags: android, mysql, android-intent

I am a beginner in android, please guide me with the following. I have a Mysql database on a webserver. I want to pull data from there into an android device and place it into the GUI already coded in the android device. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't connect Android to MySQL directly, but you can use a Webservice (e.g. a PHP script, perhaps) to act as an intermediary. Android hits the PHP script with some parameters, the PHP script handles talking to MySQL, and then returns the appropriate data in some useful format, maybe JSON.

Comment: Marc B yea i am using a webservice PHP script can you guide me with any code.

Comment: Marc B is right... I am using webservices too... I am picking data from SQL server. It works fine.

Comment: @Hiren: not really. No idea what you're trying to send back and forth, so all I could show is a skeleton, and you should be able to write that yourself anyways. But basically you'd be creating your own little mini-API to enable the android<->php<->mysql communications.

Comment: Yea Exactly how can i do that?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a service on mysql server (can be any programming language) which can be invoked by HTTPURLConnection. Service on mysql should return either JSON/XML response. In app, you can parse the xml/json response using inbuilt classes like SAX (or) DOM praser (or) JSonObject and populate the fields.